# TSQL Divide Up a Table evenly based on a Sort

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I split a table evenly based on a sort?  Here is a mock up script of what I am talking about:

Edit: I want to split the table evenly by balance into 4 different groups.  (or any number of groups).  It's important so that each group has their fair share of high and low balances.

```
DECLARE @WorkList TABLE 
(
    account_number VARCHAR(10),
    balance MONEY,
    assigned_to INT
)

DECLARE @Loop INT
DECLARE @TotalPartsToSplitEvenly INT

SET @TotalPartsToSplitEvenly = 4
SET @Loop = 1

WHILE @Loop < 50
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @WorkList (account_number, balance, assigned_to)
    VALUES ((@Loop * 5) * 1234, @Loop * 1000, NULL)

    SET @Loop = @Loop + 1
END

SELECT *
FROM @WorkList
ORDER BY balance DESC
```

I want to split the result set evenly so that everyone gets their fair share of balance.

```
account_number balance               assigned_to
-------------- --------------------- -----------
302330         49000.00              1
296160         48000.00              2
289990         47000.00              3
283820         46000.00              4
277650         45000.00              1
271480         44000.00              2
265310         43000.00              3
259140         42000.00              4
252970         41000.00              1
246800         40000.00              2
240630         39000.00              3
```

`NTILE` doesn't work for this. I am out of ideas.

Comment: Your code is meaningless to a casual reader.  You should explain what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `row_number()` mod 4:

```
select wl.*,
       (1 + (row_number() over (order by balance desc) - 1) % 4) as assigned_to
from @worklist wl;
```